# How do I copy a structure array to another by value in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, structure

I have a structure defined in a header named proc.h. 
This is defined as -

```
struct pentry{....};
extern struct pentry proctab[];
```

This header is imported in a .c file, where I try to copy this structure to another structure by value.

My syntax is-

```
#include <conf.h>
#include <kernel.h>
#include <proc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ps()
{
    struct pentry temp = proctab[0];
}
```

This gives me an error "undefined reference to memcpy" if string.h is not included. If I include string.h, it gives me several errors of the type "error: conflicting types of strncpy was here" and so on.

I tried memcpy too, and I get the exact same errors.

```
struct pentry temp;
memcpy(&temp, &proctab, sizeof(proctab[0]));
```

However, if I try a pointer, it works fine.

```
struct pentry *temp = &proctab[0];
```

Why am I not able to copy the structure by value?

Additional - I am using UNIX environment. I use "make depend" and "make" to compile. The array of structures proctab is being used in a lot of places, and I don't want to modift it in any way. Hence I'm trying to copy it by value. As a workaround, right now I'm copying individual elements of the structure and it's working. But I'd like to copy the strucutre as a whole.

Comment: What is your environment/compiler?

Comment: `extern struct pentry proctab[];` This declares `proctab` to be a pointer to type `struct pentry` and is same as `extern struct pentry *proctab;`.

Comment: If you change it to use stl arrays, you could use stl copy ( from algorithm ).

Comment: Are you working in a kernel, or in user space?  If something other than `<string.h>` defines `strncpy()` etc differently from `<string.h>`, then the other file is not designed to be used as you are using it.  You should not get a message about `memcpy()` for the assignment you show (`struct pentry temp = proctab[0];` should be clean; if the compiler wants to invoke `memcpy()` or its equivalent, that's fine — but it can't complain that you've not provided a declaration for `memcpy()`.  To copy a whole array, you have to know how big the array is and then you do use `memcpy()` or `memmove()`.

Comment: I am working in UNIX, modifying and running contents of an educational OS called XINU.

Comment: Please also post how you are compiling or make file.

Comment: XINU Is Not UNIX...Douglas Comer...  The problem with `struct pentry temp; memcpy(&temp, &proctab, sizeof(proctab[0]));` is that you should have written `memcpy(&temp, proctab, sizeof(proctab[0]));` or `memcpy(&temp, &proctab[0], sizeof(proctab[0]));`.  Are you sure your `void ps() { struct pentry temp = proctab[0]; }` code is generating an error? Can you show the exact error message?

Comment: Whatever you are doing in the above code is fine, provide more code.